# Accessing innerHTML in javascript for addEventListener

Tags: javascript, dom, error-handling, addeventlistener, innerhtml

I tried 2 pieces of code, one of them worked and the other didn't and I am not sure as to why it happened as both the code pieces look similar to me. What I want to do is to print a different piece of text every time a user clicks on a button. First, the code that didn't work as I wanted it to and the result was always **err** and each time I clicked on it, neither the text changed nor the console except for the number beside **err** kept increasing

```
function func1() {
    let x = document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML;
    if (x===""){
        x = "First click";
        console.log("err");
    }
    else if (x==="First click") {
        x = "Second click";
        console.log("err2");
    }
    else {
        x = "Third click";
    }
}

document.getElementById("click").addEventListener("click", func1);
```

And the second piece of code that worked perfectly is :

```
function func1() {
    let x = document.getElementById("test1");
    if (x.innerHTML===""){
        x.innerHTML = "First click";
        console.log("err");
    }
    else if (x.innerHTML==="First click") {
        x.innerHTML = "Second click";
        console.log("err2");
    }
    else {
        x.innerHTML = "Third click";
    }
}

document.getElementById("click").addEventListener("click", func1);
```

Comment: The variable `x` is a reference to the DOM node. Updating the value of `x` will have no effect on the DOM, while updating `x.innerHTML` will.

Comment: when you do `x = #test1.innerHTML`, you are setting it to a string with no connection to the #test1 element. any updates to `x` will not be updated in the innerHTML of the actual element. additionally for your use case i would use `innerText` instead of html

Comment: @skara9 do you mind giving a complete code by using innerText ?

Comment: @VivekBhadula I'm saying use the second code sample you provided in your question, just replacing `innerHTML` with `innerText`

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot, altho isn't there any other way to do it? As i find typing innerText or innerHTML multiple times too disturbing @skara9

Answer (score 2):

Reassigning a variable does not have any side-effects (in almost all cases) - doing `someVar = newValue` will only cause changes if other parts of the code reference `someVar` later.

When you do

```
let x = document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML;
```

you invoke the `.innerHTML` getter of the element, which returns the HTML string and puts that string into the `x` variable. Putting a new string into the `x` variable doesn't change the element. You have to assign to the `.innerHTML` property of the element in order to invoke the setter, which is why

```
x.innerHTML = "Second click";
```

works.

Comment: Thank you! This was easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use the `x =`  syntax to modify the text of the element, the closest you can get is defining a property on the window to forward the value.

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'x', { get: () => document.getElementById("test1").innerText, set: (val) => document.getElementById("test1").innerText = val });
```

```js
x // gives text value
x = 'asdf' // sets to 'asdf'
```

---

Of course this is very over the top and unnecessary for simply avoiding adding a `.innerText` and I wouldn't recommend doing all that unless it is really important for your purpose.

Simpler and safer approach would be to simply define a function.

```js
function x(v) {
  if (v) document.getElementById("test1").innerText = v;
  return document.getElementById("test1").innerText;
}
```

```js
x() // gives text value
x('asdf') // sets to 'asdf'
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help